# :hover and :active on touch in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, button, menu, hover

I have a div that has

```
.mydiv{
    background-color:white;
    color:red;
}

.mydiv:hover{
  background-color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:white;
}
```

and I would like to have nice hover-like properties also on touch devices. The behavior I get is not exactly what I want. The hover-like behavior does occur, but it is sticky. I discovered that if I instead add

```
.mydiv:active{
  background-color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:white;
}
```

then the stickiness goes away, and it works as I want. However, then the normal hover behavior (on non-touch devices) goes away. :(

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use media queries. The larges protrait mode screen width for smartphones is 480px. So you tell all screens at 480px or below a different CSS then then screen above 480px.

```css
.mydiv{
    background-color:white;
    color:red;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    .mydiv:hover{
      background-color:red;
      cursor: pointer;
      color:white;
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mydiv:active{
      background-color:red;
      cursor: pointer;
      color:white;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think that quite solves it. For example, an iPad can have a width well above 480px, yet should still have the touch (active) behavior.

Comment: you can simply raise the pixel count to also include tablets. Also combine it with portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: How would you raise the pixel count to include, say, an iPad Pro, without it also affecting desktop folks who don't use their browser at full width? I don't mind folks who have narrow browser viewports to see a "mobile" version, but I don't want th experience to be broken, which it would be if they also see the :active version as opposed to the :hover version. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There's simple solution to it. This is the code!

```js
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("DIV");
  x.style.backgroundColor="red";
  x.style.cursor="pointer";
  x.style.color="white"
}
function my2Function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("DIV");
  x.style.backgroundColor="white";
  x.style.color="red"
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}

.mydiv:active {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "mydiv" id="DIV" onmouseover="myFunction()" onmouseleave="my2Function()">
  hi
</div>
```